# JSON Validation and parsing in PHP

Tags: php, json, validation, parsing

I am parsing JSON using the following example php syntax

```
$carModel = strip_tags($_REQUEST['car']['model']);
```

The only problem is that some times the "model" array is missing from the provided JSON. When this is the case my php script shuts down when it reaches that line. Can any one recommend a way to check for the model array before parsing so that my php scrip will still run if "model" isn't present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if it's there. If not assign a default value to it:

```
$carModel = (isset($_REQUEST['car']['model'])) ? strip_tags($_REQUEST['car']['model']) : '';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it good practice to add this to every line when parsing JSON?

Comment: It's good practice for *any* input that you don't have full control over

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this is related to json, but if you want to check if a variable exists before you use it, you can do:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['car']['model']))
{
  $carModel = strip_tags($_REQUEST['car']['model']);
}
```